# How do I do for-all introduction in Isabelle?

Tags: beginner, isabelle

It's pretty easy to prove something like this:

```
theory Scratch imports Main begin

theorem "foldl (λ x y. x) a b = a"
  apply (induction b)
  by auto
```

However, rewording the theorem using the universal quantifier makes it not work any more:

```
theorem "∀ a b. foldl (λ x y. x) a b = a"
  apply (rule allI, rule allI)
  apply (induction b)  (* Unable to figure out induct rule *)
  by auto              (* Failed to apply initial proof method *)
```

The `b` in `induction b` appears to be a *separate* `b` to the `b` in the goal. (This is a guess, from looking at how more complicated examples behave.) When I try to use a simpler example (e.g. `∀ x :: nat. x < x + 1`), `by simp` just solves it automatically – which means I can't see how it's done.

How can I introduce variables in Isabelle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just successfully did $\forall$-introduction after the first `apply`. But sometimes using `rule` is too low-level.

After that command, your goal reads `⋀a b. foldl (λx y. x) a b = a`, in which meta-quantified variables can be read as *for arbitrary `a,b`*. But they are still quantified, so there's no such a (free) variable `b` on scope. So, when you want to prove something about arbitrary values, you *fix* some `a` and `b` and proceed:

```
theorem ‹∀ a b. foldl (λ x y. x) a b = a›
proof (clarify)  ― ‹\<^term>‹safe› also works here›
  fix a b
  show ‹foldl (λx y. x) a b = a›
    by (induction b) simp_all
qed
```

The `clarify` method does exactly that: clears universal quantifiers, implication antecedents, and the like. `safe` applies all eponymous rules (i.e., that give you an equivalent goal). And I've changed the comment and quote styles to a more modern one.

---

**EDIT**. The above is an Isar answer (which is the recommended idiom for writing Isabelle proofs). Without using Isar, you were probably expecting something like:

```
theorem ‹∀ a b. foldl (λ x y. x) a b = a›
  apply (intro allI)
  apply (rule List.induct_list012)
  by simp_all
```

where `intro` repeatedly applies the listed introduction rules. (I found the list induction rule by Ctrl-b completion.) But then you could use the even simpler:

```
theorem ‹∀ a b. foldl (λ x y. x) a b = a›
  by (auto intro:List.induct_list012)
```

Comment: Paradoxically, the last one also counts as an Isar proof, although I quite dislike the name of the invoked rule.